# Refactoring into java 8 lambda/stream

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

when I solve the Subset Sum problem or "P = NP" it takes 5 minutes with the following code.  I am really curious to know how much faster it would be if I were using .parallelStream.  however I don't understand how to convert the code.

```
public class MainActivity {
final static Integer[] POPS = {8897109, 12828837, 9461105, 6371773, 5965343, 5946800, 5582170, 5564635, 5268860, 4552402, 4335391, 4296250, 4224851, 4192887, 3439809, 3279833, 3095313, 2812896, 2783243, 2710489, 2543482, 2356285, 2226009, 2149127, 2142508, 2134411};
final static int TOTAL = 100000000;
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Combinations c = new Combinations(POPS, TOTAL);
    c.chooser();
}
```

}

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.paukov.combinatorics.Factory;
import org.paukov.combinatorics.Generator;
import org.paukov.combinatorics.ICombinatoricsVector;


public class Combinations {
private Integer[] POPS;
private int TOTAL;

public combinations(Integer[] pops, int total){
    this.POPS = pops;
    this.TOTAL = total;
}

public void chooser(){
    for(int i = 1; i<=POPS.length; i++){
        System.out.println(i);
        ICombinatoricsVector<Integer> initialVector = Factory.createVector(POPS);
        Generator<Integer> gen = Factory.createSimpleCombinationGenerator(initialVector, i);
        for (ICombinatoricsVector<Integer> combination : gen) {
            String temp = combination.toString();
            int size = temp.indexOf("size");
            temp = temp.substring(22, size-3);
            int sum = Adder(temp);
            if (sum == TOTAL){
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

public int adder(String combos){
    int total = 0;
    String[] parts = combos.split(", ");
    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<parts.length; i++){
        nums.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[i]));
    }
    for(int temp : nums){
        total += temp;
    }

    return total;
}
}
```

Here is the code with the string stuff taken out.  It only takes about 15 seconds now.  I realize that .parallelStream() will not reduce its time much, but could someone still at least give me some hints on how to do it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.paukov.combinatorics.Factory;
import org.paukov.combinatorics.Generator;
import org.paukov.combinatorics.ICombinatoricsVector;


public class Combinations {
private Integer[] POPS;
private int TOTAL;

public Combinations(Integer[] pops, int total){
    this.POPS = pops;
    this.TOTAL = total;
}

public void chooser(){
    for(int i = 1; i<=POPS.length; i++){
        System.out.println(i);
        ICombinatoricsVector<Integer> initialVector = Factory.createVector(POPS);
        Generator<Integer> gen = Factory.createSimpleCombinationGenerator(initialVector, i);
        for (ICombinatoricsVector<Integer> combination : gen) {
            List<Integer> temp = combination.getVector();
            int sum = adder(temp);
            if (sum == TOTAL){
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

public int adder(List<Integer> combos){
    int total = 0;
    for(Integer temp : combos){
        total+=temp;
    }
    return total;
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to get rid of all these conversions from and to `String` first. Then it might turn out that the actual operation you are performing (summing some integers) is way too simple to be accelerated by parallel computing.

Comment: you might be right since I didn't find all the combinations myself.  I used this object ICombinatoricsVector<Integer> combination if I could code that part with parallelStream it would probably make a big difference.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you included code that invoked the algorithm shown here, so we could run it ourselves and see what's taking 5 minutes. Also, please follow Java code conventions of capitalizing class names and starting method names with initial lower case.

Comment: @StuartMarks I believe I have made all the convention changes and added the main method.  I would have private messaged you this if there was a way.

Comment: No need for a private message. I think it's good to have a public comment thread about how to improve the question; it helps others. In that vein, it would have been convenient if you had linked to the library you're using. Is it [Combinatoricslib](https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/)? More importantly, you should take Holger's advice and avoid string processing. That library provides the ability to get values from the vectors; use that instead of stringifying the vector and parsing the result. You'll still have boxing/unboxing overhead though.

Comment: @StuartMarks You are correct with Combinatoricslib link.  I was just following an example and it was kicking out strings.  I didn't know I could get values out of it... I have been looking through the documentation and I don't know how to do it.  I guess I am in over my head.

Comment: That's OK; getting in over your head is how you learn. I'd advise concentrating on the basics first before tackling parallelism. For ICombinatoricsVector, you can get the value at position **n** using `getValue(n)`. But it also extends `Iterable`, which means that you can use it with a for-loop. Getting the sum of the Integers in one of these vectors should be a simple loop, involving no string conversion or parsing.

Comment: @StuartMarks  I got it.  It was actually really easy I just kept glancing over what I needed.

Comment: You should move `initialVector` out of the loop, it only needs to be created once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This runs about three times as fast on my box (i7-2600 with hyper-threading, 8 virtual cores):

```
public class Combinations {
    private Integer[] POPS;
    private int TOTAL;

    public Combinations(Integer[] pops, int total) {
        this.POPS = pops;
        this.TOTAL = total;
    }

    public void chooser() {
        ICombinatoricsVector<Integer> initialVector = Factory.createVector(POPS);

        IntStream.range(1, POPS.length + 1).parallel()
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .mapToObj(i -> Factory.createSimpleCombinationGenerator(initialVector, i))
                .flatMap(gen -> genToStream(gen, false)
                        .map(ICombinatoricsVector::getVector)
                        .filter(v -> adder(v) == TOTAL))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static int adder(Iterable<Integer> combos) {
        int total = 0;
        for (Integer temp : combos) {
            total += temp;
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static <E> Stream<ICombinatoricsVector<E>> genToStream(Generator<E> gen, boolean parallel) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliterator(gen.iterator(),
                gen.getNumberOfGeneratedObjects(), Spliterator.ORDERED), parallel);
    }
}
```

This uses a parallel stream for the outer loop, a regular stream for the inner loop, and avoids using a stream to sum the list (for speed). You can try a parallel inner stream with `genToStream(gen, true)`, but I didn't see any difference in speed.

Also, if you want a `List<List<Integer>>` of matches, just change the forEach line to `.collect(Collectors.toList());`.

Comment: @SeanVanGorder this code is awesome and it only took about 5 seconds.  I would like to ask you all sorts of questions of how it works since I can't understand it but I am sure you don't have the time.  Could you please direct me to a guide so that I may teach myself.

Comment: Well, for a quick overview, you can think of a stream like a conveyor belt or assembly line, and each map/filter/etc. call adds another machine that operates on each item as it passes. The `map` operation processes the item, the `filter` operation tests the item and dumps rejected items off the line, the `peek` operation inspects the item without changing it (usually for logging/debugging), and the line ends at a terminal operation like `collect` or `forEach`. A parallel stream means items are sent to multiple identical assembly lines which all join up before the terminal operation.

Comment: The lambdas here, like `x -> func(x)`, take each item as input (`x` is just a parameter name) and return the result of the statement or block after the `->`. For `map` this means the result replaces the item, for `filter` the result is a boolean that decides which items are rejected, etc. The notation `Cls::func` is basically shorthand for the lambda `x -> Cls.func(x)`, or possibly `x.func()` (if `x` is an instance of `Cls`). This `genToStream` implementation is the standard way to make a stream from an `Iterator`, because it just wouldn't be Java without some hideous unnecessary boilerplate.

Comment: For more details, see the tutorials on [lambdas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), and [streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html).